# How can I zoom in the Widget to cover all the area using ClipRRect on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
return Container(
      height: 450,
      width: context.width,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              child: YoutubePlayerBuilder(
                  player: YoutubePlayer(
                      controller: YoutubePlayerController(
                        initialVideoId: 'xXiSN8Tftjg',
                        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                            disableDragSeek: true,
                            enableCaption: false,
                            hideThumbnail: true,
                            hideControls: true,
                            autoPlay: true,
                            loop: true),
                      ),
                      onReady: () {
                        print('video reaady');
                      }),
                  builder: (context, player) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [player],
                    );
                  }),
            ),
    );
```

Some videos are okay but some have different aspect ratio and creating a black bar on the top and the bottom like the screenshot.

[image]

I want to zoom the widget to certain pixels in order to cover all the remaining black background area for all the videos coming in.

I've tried with ClipRRect but failed to cover all the places. Or is it possible to change the video aspect ratio? I tried to set the ratio but it only changes the picture not the video!